# Please Stop Closing Gardening Questions as OT

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do we draw the line between sustainable living and gardening?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/where-do-we-draw-the-line-between-sustainable-living-and-gardening)

There's a brigade of folks closing all Gardening questions as Off topic and pointing people over to Gardening.SE.  However the answers with the most votes in the question [Where do we draw the line between sustainable living and gardening?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/where-do-we-draw-the-line-between-sustainable-living-and-gardening) suggest that we should allow substantial overlap between Sustainability SE and Gardening SE.  Right now it looks like any question that doesn't explicitly mention sustainability and is on growing things is getting closed and directed over to Gardening.

That's stupid.  Of course people aren't going to mention sustainability explicitly, they don't have to!  It's assumed.  They came here to ask the question instead of Gardening because they want answers from people with Sustainability on the brain.  They don't want to have to wade through a whole bunch of conventional or unsustainable answers.  **And they don't want to be the ones to have to judge whether an answer is unsustainable.**  At Gardening, they will have to be.  They only want the sustainable answers to their question.  Furthermore, even the third voted answer to the "draw the line" question, suggests that we should allow questions that are about sustainably growing things.  Many of the questions that have been closed are *implicitly* about sustainbly growing things.  Sustainable agriculture deals with forest gardening, permaculture and polycultures.  So questions about encouraging connections between species (https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-to-plant-with-asparagus), ([What species of mycorrhizal fungus do well with apple trees?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-species-of-mycorrhizal-fungus-do-well-with-apple-trees)), ([How do I innoculate a 3 year old tree with a mycorrhizal fungus?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-do-i-innoculate-a-3-year-old-tree-with-a-mycorrhizal-fungus)) should be decidedly *on topic*.

Beyond that questions about actively growing food in suburban environments (https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/274/replacing-a-tree), or even in urban ones ([How do i start with vertical gardening?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/268/how-do-i-start-with-vertical-gardening)) are also integral to sustainability and implicitly about growing things for the purpose of being sustainable.  They are looking for answers about how to do it in a sustainable way.  The vertical gardening asker doesn't want to be told to buy a plastic window tower produced in China using petroleum products by forced labor.  The tree replacer wants to be told how to reuse the material from or move the existing tree.

Comment: Your answer and reasoning would be a perfectly valid addition to the discussion raised previously. Let's try and keep this discussion on one place without splitting this information between a bunch of threads.

Comment: Except it's already answered in that place, and voted up.  And this is still happening, based on the actions of five people not respecting the discussion in that quesiton.  I'm bringing it back up to point that out.  Stop voting to close those questions, respect the discussion and let those questions play out in place.